# White Magnifying Glass appears in UITextfield when long press

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

when I am performing a long press event at any text field for editing then a White circle appears but doesn't show text inside? I not able to understand whats happening.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change UIWindow background color to ClearColor.